# How do I get the userpoint description to include clickable node link?

Tags: userpoints

I would like to get a clickable link of the current node stored in the description parameter of the **userpoints_userpointsapi**

Am using the code below at the moment. Its working fine  but the link shown under the user profile is not clickable.

How can I make this link clickable whenever its displayed in anywhere else on the site for example under the user profile list of points by that user:

```
$params = array (
    'points' => round($percentage/10),
    'tid' =>16,
    'description' => '<a href="/node/'. $nid .'">'. $node->title .'</a>'
    );
userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
```

Comment: How are you outputing the points?  Is the html for the link still there but in urlencoded form?  if so just pass description through `urldecode()` before you print.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the node using the entity_type => 'node' and entity_id => $node->nid arguments, then the description will automatically be linked to the node.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately this is not possible.  Userpoints calls strip_tags which removes the html on line 1808 of userpoints.module.  You may want to patch the module to allow your html code to exist, but it could introduce a potential security vulnerability.

---

Try this snippet:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) $nodeid = arg(1);
if (isset($nodeid)) {
  $node = node_load($nodeid);
  $description = "Awarded points for doing something on " . l($node->title, '/node/' . $nodeid);
} else {
  $description = "Something awful";
}

//Add results to user point database
$params = array (
  'points' => round($percentage/10),
  'tid' =>16,
  'description' => $description,
);
userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
// end add user point
```

Comment: The result was the same. The links appear literarily including html tags. The automatically added points are displayed with clickable links however.